# dynamic form in react how to update nested state field in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My state :

```
this.state = {
        name: '',
        subCatagory: [{ name: '', price: '', customize: [] }],
    };
```

my form in react.js :

```
{this.state.subCatagory.map((subCatagory, idx) => (
                <div className="subCatagory" key={idx}>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder={`Enter Dish  #${idx + 1} name`}
                        value={subCatagory.name}
                        onChange={this.handlesubCatagoryNameChange(idx)}
                    />
                    <input
                        type="number"
                        placeholder={`subCatagory #${idx + 1} price`}
                        value={subCatagory.price}
                        onChange={this.handlesubCatagoryPriceChange(idx)}
                    />
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        onClick={this.handleRemovesubCatagory(idx)}
                        className="small"
                    >
                        Delete
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" onClick={this.addNewCust(idx)} className="small">
                        is cust availble?
                    </button>
                    {subCatagory.customize.map((customize, custIdx) => (
                        <div key={custIdx}>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                placeholder={`subCatagory #${custIdx + 1} price`}
                                value={customize.name}
                                onChange={this.handlesubCatagoryChange(
                                    idx,
                                    'customize',
                                    custIdx
                                )}
                            />
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            ))}
```

i want to update every time when a value is updated in input `handlesubCatagoryChange` and my form is dynamic one ., here i took index of first map and then index of second map but can't able to update the state in react

Answer (score 1):

You can update the item in the array with a function like this

```
handlesubCatagoryNameChange = idx => e => {
    const value = e.target.value;

    this.setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        subCatagory: subCatagory.map((x, i) => {
            if (i === idx) {
                return {
                    ...x,
                    name: value
                }
            }

            return x
        })
    }))
}
```

*(this is only for the `name`, you will need the same method for the other fields)*

This will keep your `subCategory` array immutable, and only update the item on the specified index.

For the nested array, you will do the same - something like this (if I understand correctly)

```
handlesubCatagoryChange  = (otherIdx, propertyPath, innerIdx) => e => {
    const value = e.target.value;

    this.setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        subCatagory: subCatagory.map((x, i) => {
            if (i === otherIdx) {
                return {
                    ...x,
                    [propertyPath]: x[propertyPath].map((y, j) => {
                        if (j === innerIdx) {
                            return {
                                ...y,
                                name: value
                            }
                        }

                        return y
                    })
                }
            }

            return x
        })
    }))
}
```

Comment: `handlesubCatagoryPriceChange = idx => evt => {
  const subCatagory = this.state.subCatagory.map((subCatagory, sidx) => {
   if (idx !== sidx) return subCatagory;
   return { ...subCatagory, price: evt.target.value };
  });

  this.setState({ subCatagory: subCatagory });
 };`

for single array i used map function and it worked fine but can't able do same in nested one

Comment: @User_3535 In your gist, you are not doing what I suggest in the second code example.

Comment: Yes ., can u suggest me or can u provide a gist ?

Answer (score 1):

Change button to use `event` as well

```
{this.handlesubCatagoryNameChange.bind(this,idx)}
```

Then use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
handlesubCatagoryNameChange(idx,e){
        let subCatagory = Object.assign({}, this.state.subCatagory); //creating copy of object in state
        subCatagory[idx].name = e.target.value
        this.setState({ subCatagory });
    };
```